# Passing list of objects to get method in web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

How can I pass a list of object to web API get method?
I'm not trying to post this list, only want to make some functions on this data and return a value.

I tried the following code:

```
        [Route("Save_SALE")]
        [HttpGet]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public IHttpActionResult Save_SALE(List<SL_table> SL_table)
{
                  return Ok(SL_table);
}
```

It seems to return empty list. Can anybody tell me what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)You can not pass data with "Httpget"
2)json data must be same with your class fields

example json data:

```
[
    {
        "date": "2020-11-01T10:47:25",
        "checkNo": "2020300400474",
        "siteNo": "2001",
        "siteName": "Koroglu",
        "taxId": "0122345789",
        "companyName": "AA Company MMC",
        "amount": 30,
        "description": "description main",
        "description2": "description additional"
        
    },
    {
        "date": "2020-11-06T11:17:38",
        "checkNo": "2020300400479",
        "siteNo": "2002",
        "siteName": "20 yanvar",
        "taxId": "0122345789",
        "companyName": "AB Company MMC",
        "amount": 240,
        "description": "description main",
        "description2": "description additional"

    }
]
```

and example Web API Method

```
  [HttpPost]
    
            public async Task<IActionResult> AddInvoice(List<Invoice> invoices)
            {
               return Ok(invoices)
            }
```

If you want pass data with HttpGet then use Query params

Comment: thank you , what do you mean with Query params sorry but I am kind new to web api

Comment: search for Http Query parametrs